# multiple file upload not working with formidable in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      try{
        if (files.file.name != '') {
          file_newname = dt.MD5(files.file.name + Date() + Math.random()) + '.jpg' + ;
          var file_newpath = './tmp/' + file_newname;
          fs.readFile(file_oldpath, function (err, data) {

            // Write the file
            fs.writeFile(file_newpath, data, function (err) {
              console.log('File written!');
              res.end(JSON.stringify({             
                message: 'file uploaded successfully'
              }));
            });            

          });
        }
      }catch (e) {

      }
    });
  });
```

The single image upload is working perfectly.I tried the following code

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();



files = [],
fields = [];
form.on('field', function(field, value) {
    fields.push([field, value]);
})
form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    console.log(file.name);
    files.push([field, file]);
})
form.on('end', function() {
    console.log('done');
    //res.redirect('/forms');
});
form.parse(req);
```

But only a single image gets uploaded.  i m using react in frontend. Node and express in backend.

I also tried multer. But that doesnt working

```
app.post('/getrast', upload.array('files'), function (req, res) {

     res.json({data: req.files});
     });
```

Comment: are you able to select multiple files ?

Comment: yes i provided multiple in input

Comment: could you please try form.multiles = true ?  like this, https://github.com/juhilsomaiya/node-python-project/blob/master/app.js#L38

Comment: thanks its working. but the file is created without extensio. where we append the extension? And is there a way to give response of array of filenames uploaded

Comment: Pls approve and upvote answer. 
Yes you can definitely rename your files using .rename function
use it with form.on('file') as one file will be added, you can rename it
check this https://github.com/juhilsomaiya/node-python-project/blob/master/app.js#L48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the multiple flag with the incoming form with true as value.

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.multiples = true; //use this while dealing with multiple files

files = [],
fields = [];
form.on('field', function(field, value) {
    fields.push([field, value]);
})
form.on('file', function(field, file) {

    fs.rename('add your logic here for renaming files'); // rename it here

    console.log(file.name);
    files.push([field, file]);
})
form.on('end', function() {
    console.log('done');
    //res.redirect('/forms');
});
form.parse(req);
```